# Defining a brush with a non-straight graphic as the base in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

I have designed a dragon but it isn't completely round so I am thinking to use it on **brush definition** and add this dragon on a circle stroke. It should be easy if the dragon were straight but it isn't.

[image]

**Is it possible to use this on a stroke?**

Comment: Hi Murtaza, I edited your question to better present what you want to ask--as I understood it. If things no longer represent your question, feel free to roll back my edit!

Comment: Why don't you use symbol instead it look like more appropriate for you case non ?

Comment: @inkobl I want it work as stroke, means if stroke is straight then it should be straight and if stroke is round then this should be too.